# How to fix 'Cannot access a disposed object'?

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm trying to make a **simple command prompt** using **ConsoleControl** latest version. My code is very simple :

```
public CommandPrompt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CommandPrompt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        consoleControl1.StartProcess("cmd", string.Empty);
    }

    private void CommandPrompt_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        consoleControl1.StopProcess();
    }
```

The problem is on FormClosing event. Whenever I close the window and re-open it just after (sometimes it triggers the exception just when closing), it produces a "Cannot access a disposed object" exception.

I can't seem to fix it. The problem is the `StopProcess()` method as I saw myself. So I've decided to manually **terminate the cmd process** using `Process.Kill()`, but still the same exception. It seems like, for some reason, terminating the cmd process **when the form is closing** throws this exception.

The only way that I found to terminate the process via the program is by using the command `taskkill` or `tskill`. But I want it to **automatically terminate** after the form closes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form and not close a form when you return.  When the form is closed you will get the error you are seeing.  Use my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I found the solution.
I just had to **use an instance of the form and hide it instead of closing it**.

Here's my code now :

```
public CommandPrompt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CommandPrompt_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }

    private void CommandPrompt_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        consoleControl1.StopProcess();
        consoleControl1.StartProcess("cmd", string.Empty);
    }
```

And when showing the form :

```
private CommandPrompt cmd = new CommandPrompt();

    private void Button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Show();
    }
```

Hope it can help other people too!